# pro lighting skies does not work properly on blender 2.81

Tags: add-on

I hope this is the right place to put my problem.
Perhaps due to the new node mapping, the advanced features of this addon do not work on blender 2.81. For example it is impossible to change the horizon level.
I bought a copy a few years ago and have already written to Blenderguru twice without getting an answer. Do you have any advice?
thanks